# Getting sonar and bumper data p2os

Tags: ros, p2os, pioneer-3dx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I just wanted to know if there is some example on getting sonar and bumper data from a pioneer3dx using p2os, I can't find anything. I thought it was like getting pose data but now I think it's nothing like that. Can you help me?

It seems like p2os does not offer access to bumper data, but is it possible in any way?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/137466/getting-sonar-and-bumper-data-p2os/) by [NullX4](https://answers.ros.org/users/11546/nullx4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-03-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

p2os_driver publishes sonar data on the `sonar` topic.  The data is a special data type `p2os_driver::SonarArray` whose definition you can see in `p2os_driver/msg/SonarArray.msg`.  You may need to enable sonar via the `~use_sonar` parameter.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2014-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NullX4](https://answers.ros.org/users/11546/nullx4/) on 2014-03-11**:
Thank you very much, but what about the bumpers?

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-03-14**:
It doesn't look like p2os_driver provides bumper data, from what I can see.

**Comment by [NullX4](https://answers.ros.org/users/11546/nullx4/) on 2014-03-15**:
So what can I do to access to that data?

**Comment by [sealguy77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20929/sealguy77/) on 2015-04-07**:
I went into `p2os_driver/src/p2os.cc` and changed false in

`n_private.param("use_sonar", use_sonar_, false);` to true;

however, `rostopic echo /sonar` still does not produce ranges.  It also doesn't even sound as if the sonar sensors are running.  How can I get the sonar working?